OLED Supply voltage for display
I am new to OLED design,
When I read this datasheet OLED 128x64 - Vishay, a line Supply voltage for display shows Min-Max: 10V - 15V. Meanwhile in 0.96" OLED is just using 3.3V can run it.
My first question: Does it need 10V-15V to run this display? If not when do we care about that value?
My second question: Depending on 0.96" OLED it seems there is an internal boot circuit in that driver is that right?

It doesn't appear that you need to supply that voltage. It looks like you only need to connect a cap to the Vcc pin and the supply will boost 3.3V

Thanks, I just confused about that there have 2 supply voltage and when I use that module in the past it just need 3.3V

The OLED from Vishay has a built-in controller that has its own DC-DC converter.  You can just use that and connect a cap between Vcc and Vss, otherwise you must provide 12 V to Vcc (10 to 15 V).
The OLED from Adafruit is utilizing the built-in DC-DC converter by doing this.

Thanks, in any case that I will need provide 12V to Vcc ?

Only if you want to.  It is optional to provide the 12V.  Feel free to just add the capacitor and use the built-in converter.
